# Set the background of SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to set the SeekBar like this:

[image]

But my SeekBar is looking like this:

[image]

That's mean it over the two small "sun"

Here is my code:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/background_custom"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_custom"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_back_ground"
        />
```

Xml of background_custom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        >
        <shape>

            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="50dp" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>

                <solid android:color="#11ff00" />
                <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Xml of thumb_custom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffe38c" />
    <size
        android:width="35dp"
        android:height="35dp" />
    <corners android:radius="35dp" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/led_sang"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already solve this problem by replace this line `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/background_custom"`
to `android:progressDrawable="#80FFFF00"`. This will make the 50% transparent of the yellow color.

Answer (score 5):

try this,

set seekbar.

```
<SeekBar 
            ....
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
            ....
/>
```

in res/drawable write progress.xml like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

write thumb.xml in res/drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_fill" />
</selector>
```

hope it's work.

Answer (score 1):

Your seekbar :

```
<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/slider"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="30dp"              
 android:max="5"
 android:progress="0"
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable" />
```

progress_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
     <shape>
          <corners android:radius="10dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
     </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <clip
         android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="left">
         <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/greenStart"
                    android:centerColor="@color/greenMid"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="@color/greenEnd"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
     </clip>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documenatation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html); `SeekBar` is a `ProgressBar` so play around secondary progress and primary progress drawables..

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
           <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/brightbar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/versepage_seekboar_w"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/Device"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:maxHeight="2dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
                android:thumb="@drawable/ic_slider_thumb1" >
            </SeekBar>

seekbar.xml

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="1dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/seekbar_clr2"
            android:startColor="@color/seekbar_clr2" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/seekbar_clr2"
                android:startColor="@color/seekbar_clr" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/seekbar_clr"
                android:startColor="@color/seekbar_clr" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```